# Query to get the list of tables and the number of columns

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there any query such that I can get the list of tables with the number of columns in each table for a selected database on a local server.

Please forward your ideas if any...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT t.table_name,
         COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON c.table_name = t.table_name
   WHERE t.table_catalog = 'your_database'
     AND t.table_schema = 'your_schema'
GROUP BY t.table_name
```

### Reference

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
select TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) 
from information_schema.columns
group by TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.name as tablename, COUNT(*) as columns 
from sys.tables s 
inner join information_schema.columns i on s.name = i.TABLE_NAME  
group by s.name
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: It seems odd that you query `sys.tables` for the table names, but then you don't use `sys.columns` for the column names..... I would recommend to **EITHER** use the SQL Server specific `sys.*` catalog views, **OR** use the ANSI standard INFORMATION_SCHEMA views - but don't start to mix those two.....